# run jekyll server on window 10 Configuration file: none

Tags: ruby, powershell, jekyll

When I set up GEM on **a not master branch** following this `doc` http://jekyllrb.com/docs/windows/#installation
and run this command `jekyll s`on that branch, it throw me this WARN

```
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      listen (< 3.1, ~> 3.0)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:40:in `block in setup': You have already activated jekyll-sass-converter 1.4.0, but your Gemfile requires jekyll-sass-converter 1.3.0. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:25:in `map'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:25:in `setup'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.5/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `setup'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.3.0/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:36:in `require_from_bundler'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.3.0/exe/jekyll:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/bin/jekyll:22:in `load'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/bin/jekyll:22:in `<main>'
```

I clean with `gem cleanup listen` it not work with `jekyll s` but it run with `bundle exec jekyll s`
I even run `bundle exec jekyll serve --force_polling` and `bundle exec jekyll serve --watch`
it return `Configuration file: none`

so watch happen ? can I be able to use `jekyll s` only ?

can I using jekyll tempates   ?

### Update

I downgrade Ruby to 2.2 and reinstall bundles, server is now running but still no Configuration file `Configuration file: none`

shoul I manually create one ? `touch`

Comment: Why would you need to use `jekyll`? What’s wrong with `bundle exec jekyll`? After all, that’s how bundles work. Of course, you still have an option to cheat the `cmd` with aliases and stuff, but I barely see any reason for that.

Comment: I want to build a static page by 'jekyll', 'bundle exec jekyll s' help the server will run at ...:4000, I  just found out that bundles do not work well due to version or something, so I downgrade ruby to 2.2, everything work now, local server is running, but there is 'Configuration file: none', what should I do next ? manually 'touch' one ?

Comment: `> jekyll s

Configuration file: none

Source: C:/codes/tom031.github.io

       Destination: C:/codes/tom031.github.io/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
                    done in 0.047 seconds.
  Please add the following to your Gemfile to avoid polling for changes:
    gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for 'C:/codes/tom031.github.io'
Configuration file: none
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.`

Comment: I don’t see any problem. This is not even a warning. Unless you need the specific configuration, you are fine.

Comment: Yep, I think so, the server run fine, I may forget to install bundles with ruby 23, but I don't have Configuration file, is that till fine to use jekyll templates or how to create one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I found out the solution for this, follow that `doc` doesn't help me to creat a jekyll template for the site. I can do manually by `jekyll new` ../.. to a new dir and copy those file I want to the repo I want and commit it. everything is fine for me.
Thankyou **mudasobwa**. I just try to play with jekyll and git for a week so. it my bad :(